# How to apply groupBy keyword on pivot table in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have pivot table `users_logs` which has many columns and one of them is `event_date`. I want to retrieve all data which is associated with particular user. I have done it by I can't use groupBy() keyword because it is returning error.

```
 $GameLogs = User::with(['gamelogs' => function ($query)
{
    $query->where('type', '=', 'play');
    $query->groupBy('event_date');
}])->find(request()->user()->id);
```

Can someone kindly guide me how can I fix the issue. I would appreciate. Thank you so much.

Error is

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'o*******_db.g***s.i`
```

Comment: It will help us if you add the error you have

Comment: what results are you expecting with a groupBy on `event_date`. all information in those rows need to be aggregated .

Comment: @N69S I have edited kindly check it

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `groupBy`, the selected fields need to be aggregated in `strict mode`

```
$GameLogs = User::with(['gamelogs' => function ($query)
    {
        $query->where('type', '=', 'play');
        $query->groupBy('event_date', 'user_id');
        $query->select('event_date', 'user_id');
    }])
    ->find(request()->user()->id);
```

Comment: I am getting following error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'o*****_db.u********s.user_id' isn't in GROUP BY `

Comment: @ImranAbbas my bad, you do need to `groupBy` on the user id, or the second query wont work